# unexpected behaviour in multiline edit in winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a program of painting a text in multiline edit using windows api in c++. It consists of `WM_PAINT` message which paints the text in client area, but the caret shows unexpected behaviour in edit. It sometimes does not print characters, sometimes printed characters hides.

The code is

```
#define UNICODE
/*
**
**ALL HEADER FILES
**
*/
#include<wchar.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<resource.h>
/*
**
**ALL DEFINES CONSTANT
**
*/
#define WINVER 0x0A00
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
using namespace std;
HWND hwnd_handle;
HWND hw;
HINSTANCE his;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hvalue,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{
his=hvalue;
/////com=nCmdShow;
LPWSTR myname=L"MY WINDOWS CLASS";
MSG msg={0};
WNDCLASSW wc;
wc.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_BTNFACE;
wc.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.lpszMenuName=NULL;
wc.lpszClassName=myname;
wc.hCursor=NULL;
wc.cbClsExtra=0;
wc.cbWndExtra=0;
wc.style=0;
wc.hInstance=hvalue;
wc.lpfnWndProc=WindowProcedure;
if(!RegisterClassW(&wc))
{
return 0;
}
///////main window
hwnd_handle=CreateWindowW(myname,L"CODE EDITOR",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,240,80,600,600,NULL, NULL,hvalue, NULL);
ShowWindow(hwnd_handle,nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd_handle);
////////HWND hwnd=CreateWindowW(L"STATIC",L"CODE EDITOR",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,24,8,60,6,hwnd_handle, NULL,hInstance, NULL);
while(GetMessageW(&msg,NULL,NULL,NULL))
{
TranslateMessage(&msg);
DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(msg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{
/////main_structure(hwnd);
hw=CreateWindowW(TEXT("edit"),TEXT(""), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_AUTOVSCROLL ,3,0,600,600,hwnd,NULL,his,NULL);
}
    break;

case WM_COMMAND:
{
/////menu_function(hwnd,wParam);
}

    break;


case WM_PAINT:
{
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        RECT info;
        HBRUSH hbrush;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hw,&ps);
        wcout<<"vishal";
TextOut(hdc,20,20,L"vishak",6);
EndPaint(hw,&ps);
}
    break;


case WM_DESTROY:
PostQuitMessage(0);
break;

default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
break;
}
}
///////all men
```

Comment: why ``wcout`` in ``WM_PAINT``? It's not going to print anything on your window

Comment: this is already your 7 or 8 account here. recognizable coding style and name patterns. ask one question, and create new account for ask similar another

Comment: @OP Trying to do unorhtodox or "fancy" things in a Windows API program requires excellent knowledge of the Windows API.  Otherwise you're just guessing as to how to implement what you're trying to implement.  Instead of guessing or trying to be the blind pig trying to find the acorn, find code written by an experienced WinAPI programmer, or from a Windows API book that mimics what you want to implement.

Comment: This is a fair question. But why do you keep making user accounts? Just use one user account. I wouldn't spend time answering the question since it is unlikely that you will read the answer, or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an edit control as the client area of your window don't handle WM_PAINT yourself; instead add the text to the edit control (using SendMessage with EM_SETTEXT or possibly EM_REPLACESEL) and let it do the drawing.

Also, you should handle WM_SIZE and set the edit control to the actual client area size.